# How to get list of all dir/files belong to a user

Tags: ubuntu

1 - How can I get list of all files and directories with permission details, which belong to a particlular user.

2- How can I get all details of a file or directory like it's owner, group, permissions etc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `find -ls`:

```
find /some/path -user username -ls
```

Answer (score 5):

To list all files including their permissions you can use `ls -al` or to do so recursively `ls -alr`
You can then filter those results with grep to get particular ones (such as ones owned by a username)

```
ls -alR | grep ' username '
```

Answer (score 0):

To find all files that belong to a particular user, use find / -user username. Then you can use ls -al on the individual files.

Answer (score 0):

```
find /path/to/dir/ -user <user> -name "*.dat"
```

Also works with -group option for finding files which belong to a group