# Any command to check all files and folder owner / group and permission on linux

Tags: linux, apache, command

I need a command to check all folder and files owner/ group permissions on linux server.

I have several websites and crons running the server. The idea is to get all files / folder in any website folder or crons having a owner apache. Which will list out the files and folder names whose owner is "apache" throughout the server

Comment: possible duplicate of:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11647360/how-to-get-list-of-all-dir-files-belong-to-a-user

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -R -l
```

However, I'd strongly urge you to go through sub-directories one at a time and not hit your server root with this command. You'll be there a while and the output might be more than you can easily sort through at a go.

Answer (score 0):

You can use find:

```
find /var/www/ -ls -user apache
```

-ls if for fancy output

also, there is

```
find /var/www -ls -not -user apache
```

to find all files that not belong to apache :)